# Increment individual values in array Java

Tags: java, arrays

I want to know how to increment certain indexes in an array.

```
int indexArrayHIS[] = new int[15];
int indexArrayFIX[] = new int[20];
```

`indexArrayHIS[]` is an array consisting out of index values:
6 9 9 17 0 19 16 1 0 7 1 18 16 8 10

I want fill `indexArrayFIX[]` with the number of each index instance. For example, there are 2 "9s" so at index 9 of `indexArrayFIX[]` I want to display a 2:

`indexArrayFIX[]` should output:

2 2 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 2 1 1 1 0

Hope this makes sense

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Why not just?

```
for (int i = 0; i < indexArrayHIS.length; i++) {
    indexArrayFIX[indexArrayHIS[i]]++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to be on the right track. I used two for loops because of the difference in length of the arrays and I got: 40 40 0 0 0 0 20 20 20 40 20 0 0 0 0 0 40 20 20 20 0